# Are there any way to register in-house application in google apps marketplace with FQDN?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

I belongs IT Section which provides and distributes Google Apps and its related service in our company.
Our section has disabled Drive SDK in Google Apps admin Console because of our company policy.
However, many developers requested Drive api in our company.
So, we started registering developer's drive application in google apps marketplace to allow it.
After our registration, developers could use drive api.

However, recently our registration process has stuck in uploading on Chrome Web Store.
(*Please take a look at See step 8.)
Strictly speaking, chrome web store publishing status become rejected.
Moreover, we received app removal notification from chromewebstore-dev-support@google.com, like "Chrome Web Store: Removal notification for app name."
But we have no idea why this app has been rejected.

Here is our step we used to do.

1. In google developers console, I accessed api manager, and make drive api enabled.
2. Access drive SDK settings to register app icon and open URL, and save it.
   *About open URL, we assume intranet FQDN is forbidden, so we set http://www.google.com as open URL.
3. In OAuth Concent, type service name and save it.
4. From api manager, enable Google Apps Marketplace SDK.
5. We set application name, description, register icon, support URL and drive api scope(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) and save it.
6. Also prepare zip file for Chrome Web Store that includes manifest json and app icon.
   *In manifest json, we wrote app name, description, web app URL(we set google sites) and write as domain-installable.
7. Upload zip file to chrome web store, icon, screeen shot, promotional tile images, set web site(we set google sites.), category and languages.
8. In the end, set Visibility option as private and everyone at mydomain.
9. After published both chrome web store and google apps marketplace, access to marketplace to find published app in our domain.
10. allow access of drive app in marketplace.
    *Above processes were executed on September in 2015, 
    I believe developer console UI has been dramatically changed for now, so these steps might not match current steps.

**### Questions ###**

Considering above results, I would like to confirm things below.

1. I would like to confirm our steps above is correct or not for registering drive application in Google App Marketplace. 
   By referring Both Apps Marketplace Guides and Apps Marketplace Frequently Asked Questions, I could not find detail for specific steps.
2. I are wondering whether we must obtain or prepare domain for web application and it must be open on the web or not.
3. Are there any way to register in-house application in google apps marketplace without publishing on the web(wondering can use FQDN or not).
4. Is it possible to create Google Apps Marketplace App using service account or client application with Drive API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**1. I would like to confirm our steps above is correct or not for registering drive application in Google App Marketplace. By referring Both Apps Marketplace Guides and Apps Marketplace Frequently Asked Questions, I could not find detail for specific steps.**

You seem to have done the steps right. But just to be safe, you can check out [Publish your App](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing) page on the apps marketplace documentation.

> *Steps to Publish the app*
>
> 1. Go to the Chrome Web Store developer dashboard
> 2. Upload the zip file
> 3. Add a detailed description of your app for the Marketplace listing
> 4. Add your screenshot(s) and promotional tiles for the Marketplace isting
> 5. Add the URLs for your app's websites
> 6. Set the category, region, language(s), and other configuration details
>
> Note: To publish a private, domain-only app, skip the next step and see the instructions below.
> To publish a Marketplace app that is only visible within your own domain, do not use the listing review request form. Instead, on the developer dashboard, locate the "Visibility options" section and select "Private / Everyone at yourdomainname.com" before you publish

**2. I are wondering whether we must obtain or prepare domain for web application and it must be open on the web or not.**

I'm not sure what you mean by this question, but once the domain has been set and app published, the application will appear in the "For [your domain]" section in the Google Apps Marketplace available on admin.google.com

**3. Are there any way to register in-house application in google apps marketplace without publishing on the web(wondering can use FQDN or not).**

If you mean private company-wide application, I think Google Apps for Work can do this feature (this will incur additional charge to you though)

**4. Is it possible to create Google Apps Marketplace App using service account or client application with Drive API?**

Yes, Drive API also uses [Domain-wide delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) in which the domain admin can grant 3rd party apps access to user data.